# Taskwarrior - how to display actual *date* that task is due

Tags: customization, taskwarrior

I don't want to see the number of days left before something is Due.

```
ID Age   Due Description        Urg 
 1 33min 9d  Do Stuff           8.33
```

I want to see the actual date that it's due, like below.

```
ID Age   Due         Description        Urg 
 1 33min 2022-04-27  Do Stuff           8.33
```

Is there an easy way to modify `~/.taskrc` ?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution. Use:

```
$ task list
```

Result:

```
ID Age   Project  Tags    Due        Description   Urg
 1 33min                  2022-04-27 Do Stuff      8.33
```

Reference: https://taskwarrior.org/docs/report.html#modifiable